# Speed up for-loop in Cython

Tags: python, cython

I am still at the beginning to understand how Cython works.
This snippet shows one of the slow parts of my program and I am wondering whether this for loop can be improved.
It still pretty much looks like the original Numpy version, but I added the cdef's and int-conversion.

```
cdef Py_ssize_t i, j
cdef double ii, jj

for ii in np.arange(startx, endx+1, 0.1):
    for jj in np.arange(starty, endy+1, 0.1):
        if my_condition(ii, jj):
            i = <int>ii
            j = <int>jj
            data[i, j] += 1
```

Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: It doesn't look like you ever change `ii` or `jj`, and you completely ignore the values of `i` and `j` from the `for` loops. Also, using `np.arange` with a floating-point step is a terrible idea whether or not you're using Cython. I'd recommend `np.linspace`, but I don't think Cython knows how to optimize that.

Comment: Casting is also expensive in general and should also be moved out of loops if possible.

Comment: Overall, this code just doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Sorry, I updated the code. ii and jj are used as increments which are then "converted" to indices of the 2d data array.

Answer (score 5):

Study the cython example in

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.nditer.html

That uses `nditer` to hand out the array elements.

And

https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/src/userguide/memoryviews.html

which demonstrates the use of memoryviews (and C arrays) to rapidly iterate over the values.

Either way your goal is to let cython access the databuffer directly rather than by way of the numpy functions.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19261146)

Comment: @gonczor, those are in the official docs of the relevant modules. If the docs move, users can still search for pages of the same name.  Two years later the links are still valid, while the question is long forgotten, except for an old review stack.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a old question, but i had the same problem and found this simple solution.

https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/3310#issuecomment-707252866

```
for i in range(start, stop, step):
    ...
```

to this:

```
i = start - step
for _ in range(((stop - start) + (step - 1))//step):
    i += step
    ...
```